# Kernel Debugging in VS2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, kernel, remote-debugging

I'm having a fair bit of difficulty in trying to get VS2015 Community running on 2 separate computers to enable remote kernel debugging over the network. Both PCs are running on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Here's the IPs:

```
192.168.1.79 - Host
192.168.1.84 - Target
```

On the target I ran as administrator:

```
bcdedit /debug on
bcdedit /dbgsettings net hostip:192.168.1.79 port:55252
```

When I try to connect to it from the host in VS2015 I put in 192.168.1.84 as the host, then the key and the hostip and port listed above. It says it can't connect to 192.168.1.84:50005 even though I put the port as 55252?

I followed this article here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439346(v=vs.85).aspx

The hostip on the target should be pointing to 192.168.1.79 (host) right? Are there any other services I need to start or am I missing anything? I tried a reboot too.

Comment: There is no point in trying to use VS2015 Community to do kernel debugging.  Use a proper kernel debugger, available in the SDK.  Separate install required.  Do make sure that this is *actually* what you want to do, sounds like you'll have a bit of a learning curve ahead if you do.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use WinDbg directly? I'm not sure what you mean when you say "use a proper kernel debugger, available in the SDK." I'm aware that I have a learning curve, any pointers would help. I want to learn both creating hardware drivers for USB as well as virtual drivers for making certain hardware devices available over TCP/UDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've run:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Remote\x64\WDK Test Target Setup x64-x64_en-us.msi

After you've installed the WDK/VS Tools and BEFORE you connect to the remote debugger with the host computer. I had to read the above from this separate article on provisioning.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1

It's doing all of its copying now. The host/target nomenclature can be a little confusing I would prefer it to just be source/destination as I usually instinctively think of a host in terms of a destination not a source.

Comment: so this issue has been resolved, am I right? If so, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members:)

Comment: Sure, it wouldn't let me accept the answer right away, and I was questioning based on what Hans said about needing to use a different debugger, although it seems I don't. 

One important side note I'll mention, is that the debugging process creates a whole new user account on the target machine and you won't be able to see it logged in from RDP, you'll have to physically be at that target computer in order to accept the driver installation. Stumped me for a while because the target machine was in my media room and the projector was off.